# one time only one record is active?

Tags: trigger, validation-rule

Attachment and checkbox is true then show error message record already activated.

I tried this trigger

```
trigger con on contact (before insert) { 

Boolean active= false; 

    if (Trigger.isBefore) { 


                  email.Adderror('Record already activated'); 
       else active= false; 
            } 
}
```

Comment: Vipin you need trigger. You need to query record and check if there is an already activated record is present then show error

Comment: so, the user should not be able to add attachment to activated record?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to apply validation rule on checkbox?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110408/how-to-apply-validation-rule-on-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger before insert, before update you can achieve this. You can put SOQL Query also in trigger to check the activated record. If that record exist then you throw error.

Comment: Could someone explain me please why this answer is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code.This will help you.

```
trigger trig_IsActive on eTMFFolder__c (before insert) { 

Boolean isFirstTime = false; 
Set<string> typeSet = new Set<string>();
    if (Trigger.isBefore) { 

        if (Trigger.isInsert) { 
            for (eTMFFolder__c fol : Trigger.new) { 
               if(fol.isActive__c)
                  typeSet.add(fol.Type__c);
            } 
           List<eTMFFolder__c > folList = [select id from eTMFFolder__c  WHERE Type__c  IN: typeSet];
          if(folList.size() > 0)
                Trigger.new[0].Adderror('Record already activated');
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If user inserting 2 records and first records and first record `isActive__c` false but second record `isActive__c` true then first will receive an error.?

Comment: @Ratan yes it is but it is a sample code. There are many case which come when you write final code. OP need to handle and bulkfy this code.

Comment: @VipinIndora add `before update` event as well

Comment: @VipinIndora test may be some other records are checked

Comment: @VipinIndora are you doing this in bulk update?

Comment: update your SOQL  `List<eTMFFolder__c > folList = [select id from eTMFFolder__c  WHERE Type__c  IN: typeSet AND isActive__c = True];`

Comment: `else insert folList;` remove this part

Comment: @VipinIndora glad to know your code is finally working.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a before insert trigger which will check the Type__c and isActive__c field if found a single record with the same type and isActive__c equal true then Use addError method.